# VBA selecting visible cells after filtering

Tags: vba, excel, filter, filtering

The following code applies filters and selects the top 10 items in column B after some filters are applied to the table.  I have been using this for many different filtered selection, but I came across a problem with one of my filter combinations.

I found that when there is only one item in column B after filtering, it doesn't copy that one cell - instead it copies the entire row and seems to be a strange selection.

When I manually add one more item to this filter (total 2), then it copies it fine. Any ideas on why this code won't work when there is only one item?

```
Sub top10()

Dim r As Range, rC As Range
Dim j As Long

'Drinks top 10
Worksheets("OLD_Master").Columns("A:H").Select
Selection.sort Key1:=Range("H1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Worksheets("OLD_Master").Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(     _
    "CMI*"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
Worksheets("OLD_Master").Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=5,   Criteria1:="Drinks"

Set r = Nothing
Set rC = Nothing
j = 0

Set r = Range("B2", Range("B" &     Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each rC In r
    j = j + 1
    If j = 10 Or j = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rC

Range(r(1), rC).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Worksheets("For Slides").Range("P29").PasteSpecial
Worksheets("OLD_Master").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: If you apply `Specialcells` to only one cell, it actually applies to the entire used range of the sheet. You should test the count before using it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rory helpfully points out:

> If you apply Specialcells to only one cell, it actually applies to the entire used range of the sheet.

Now we know what the problem is, we can avoid it! The line of code where you use `SpecialCells`:

```
Set r = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Instead, set the range first, test if it only contains one cell, then proceed...

```
Set r = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
' Check if r is only 1 cell
If r.Count = 1 Then
    r.Copy
Else ' Your previous code
    Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rC In r
        j = j + 1
        If j = 10 Or j = r.Count Then Exit For
    Next rC
    Range(r(1), rC).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End If
```

Note, you're assuming there is even *one* row still visible. It might be that the `.End(xlUp)` selects row 1 if there is no visible data, you may want to check which row this is first too!

---

Aside: You really should be fully qualifying your ranges, i.e. instead of

```
 Set r = Range("B2")
```

You should use

```
Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("B2")
```

This will save you some confusing errors in future. There are shortcuts you can take, for example saving repetition using `With` blocks or declaring sheet objects.

```
' using With blocks
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    Set r = .Range("B2")
    Set s = .Range("B3")
    ' ...
End With

' Using sheet objects
Dim sh as Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
Set r = sh.Range("B2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Rory

```
Specialcells
```

Doesn't work with one cell selected.  Adapted by doing the following:

......

```
For Each rC In r
    j = j + 1
    If j = 10 Or j = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rC

If j = 1 Then
    Range(r(1), rC).Copy
Else
    Range(r(1), rC).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End If

Worksheets("For Slides").Range("P29").PasteSpecial
Worksheets("OLD_Master").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't that be: `Range(r(1), rC).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`?