# Selecting 1st 10 Rows of visible Cells in VBA Filtered Table

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, extract

New to Coding & VBA and this is my first attempt at trying to Select and Copy the **1st 10 rows of visible data** together with the table **Header** in a Table that I have filtered using VBA Macro. I used examples of code in this link on stackoverflow. [VBA selecting visible cells after filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065610/vba-selecting-visible-cells-after-filtering).  This particular example allows me to learn how to copy the values in a single column. I would like to copy the values for the entire Row, or some of the columns depending on which is easier.

```
Sub LPRDATA()


Dim TYEAR    As String
TYEAR = Range("TYEAR").Value
Dim QUARTER    As String
QUARTER = Range("QUARTER").Value
Dim r As Range, rC As Range
Dim j As Long


Sheets("CONTROL").Select
Sheets("DATA").Visible = True
Sheets("CONTROL").Select
Sheets("10").Visible = True
Sheets("DATA").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").ListObjects("tblData").Sort.SortFields.Clear
     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
     Range("tblData[[#Headers],[Sn '#]]").Select

Range("tblData[[#Headers],[Year]]").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblData").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="LPR"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblData").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=TYEAR
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblData").Range.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=QUARTER


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").ListObjects("tblData").Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("tblData[[#All],[Score]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").ListObjects("tblData").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Set r = Nothing
Set rC = Nothing
j = 0
Set r = Range("C1", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each rC In r
j = j + 1
If j = 11 Or j = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rC

Range(r(1), rC).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("10").Select
Range("C7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi.   Not tested but you want something like this: `Range(r, r.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`.  This copies all visible cells from r (which if I've correctly read your code is the top left row of the table) to the bottom right of the table (the 2 .Ends find this location).  A good tip is to use the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b).  You can use this to convert manual actions into VBA.  Very handy.

Comment: I used the Macro recorder originally but it defines the exact e.g., A1:X345, rather than the first 10 rows of the visible data.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've stripped away some of your code, to make this example easier to follow.

```
' Sorts a table in Excel.
' Then filters table for first 10 records.
' Then copies/pastes.
Sub Example()
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet       ' Spreadsheet that contains the table.
    Dim sourceLO As ListObject      ' Table that contains the data.
    Dim targetRange As Range        ' Where to copy data to.

    ' Populate vars.
    Set sourceWS = ActiveSheet
    Set sourceLO = sourceWS.ListObjects("tblData")
    Set targetRange = Range("10!C7")

    ' Sort the table.
    With sourceLO.Sort
        .SortFields.Add Range("tblData[[#All], [Score]]"), xlSortOnValues, xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Limit to first ten rows (update field to select limiting column).
    sourceLO.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="10", Operator:=xlTop10Items

    ' Copy currenlty visible cells.
    sourceLO.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    targetRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
End Sub
```

The line starting `sourceLO.Range.AutoFilter...` limits the table to the first 10 recrods.

The line starting `sourceLO.Range.SpecialCells...` copies only the visible rows (i.e. the first 10).  If you want to limit the copy/paste to certain columns use this syntax:

```
Range("tblData[Header 1], tblData[Header 2]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider instead using a loop to go through row by row and find the first ten rows that match your criteria, without using the filter.

Unless you need the filter to visually display the data to the user in a particular way, a loop is potentially more flexible and easier to code.

You could also consider storing your values in variables instead of using copy-paste - personally I find it a bit of an annoyance when a macro wipes my clipboard :)

I normally use this page to refer back to for the syntax for loops in vba:
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Comment: Thank you Bridget

Comment: Thank you Bridget. I understand the approach. My objective is to find the top 10 scores, in this year, during this quarter, of this report type.  Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in VBA. I tried doing it using formulae, but whilst I could identify the top 10 scores, I couldn't get rest of the row (even using index and match) as I had duplicate values in the scores.

Comment: Looks like destination-data 's response below is perfect in that case :)