# VBA: failed to copy the first 20 rows of filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I was reading the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402803/selecting-1st-10-rows-of-visible-cells-in-vba-filtered-table) and tried to copy the first 20 rows (exclude header) from the filtered table. However, the last line gave me an error. What did I do wrong here ?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HelloWorld")
    wb.Activate
    ws.Activate

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If ws.Range("A1:L11470").AutoFilter Then
        ws.Range("A1:L11470").AutoFilter
    End If
    ws.Range("A1:L11470").AutoFilter
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G1:G11470"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ws.Range("$A$1:$L$11470").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>-"
    ws.Range("$A$1:$L$11470").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="10", Operator:=xlTop10Items   ' <-- Error here
End Sub
```

The error is as follow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would take a slightly different approach to achieve the end you seem to be looking for.  The code suggested below does the following based on my interpretation of your question:

1. Sort the data range A:L on the sheet “HelloWorld” by column G
2. Set a filter such that column A = 10 and column K <> “-“
3. Counts the first 20 filtered (visible) rows on the HelloWorld sheet and copies them (in this demonstration to Sheet2)

If this isn’t exactly what you were looking for, please comment & I’ll adjust accordingly.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestTop20()
Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, i As Integer, LastRow As Long, EndData As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HelloWorld")

'Determine the last 'possible' row of data
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Sort your data on column G
ws.Columns("A:L").Sort _
Key1:=ws.Range("G2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

'Set the filter on columns K & A
With ws.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=10"
    .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>-"
End With

'Determine what the last visible row is - up to 20
i = 0
For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        i = i + 1
            If i = 20 Then
                EndData = c.Row
                Exit For
            End If
    End If
Next c

If EndData < 20 Then MsgBox "Less than 20 records were detected"

'Copy the first 20 filtered records
ws.Range("A2:A" & EndData).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.Goto ws.Range("A1")

End Sub
```