# How to move to next, 2nd row on Excel cell F6 when it is Filtered?

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb = $xl.WorkBooks.Open('C:\Users\steph\Desktop\MASTER ACCOUNT4.xlsx')
$ws = $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1)
$xl.Visible = $true

$headerRange = $ws.Range("a1", "f1") 
$headerRange.AutoFilter(1, "GOLDMANSACH") | Out-Null                 
$ws.Cells.Item(1, 6).Select()
```

The code above is already filtered in Excel to "GOLDMANSACH". Therefore, row 1,2,3,4,5 is gone because it is Merrill Lynch and Blackstone. GOLDMANSACH starts at row F6. I have trouble moving to the next row, because I ask my code to move to cell F1.

I encounter a problem when I try to code to move one row below. It would go to row F2, which hidden by the filter instead of F6. Can you please help me on this. It has been stressful figuring this out. That's my first question.

Comment: have you tried something like: `$cr=$ws.Cells.Item(1,6).CurrentRegion;$cr=$cr.Offset(1,0).Resize($cr.Rows.Count-1,$cr.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(12).Select()` for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/43066685/4496560

Comment: I see the entire chart is highlighted. However, I was wondering if I can select only one cell. From F1 to F6, Just one cells needs to be moved down because filtering.

Comment: `$ws.Cells.Item(1,6).CurrentRegion.Columns.Item(6).Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(12).Areas.Item(1).Cells.Item(1).Select()`