# VBA How to get range filtered and sorted in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am new on VBA and this is my problem :

```
Sheet 
A          B                C
TOTO       300              Keep
JOHN       200              Keep          
JOHN       100              Keep
ROBERTO    300
```

The goal is to get this range in the userform to create checkbox and textbox for each row after a filter on C = Keep and sort by A and B.

I have tried this but the number of rows is still zero:

```
Set rng1 = Ws.Cells

rng1.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Keep"
rng1.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("B1"), order2:=xlAscending
For i = 1 To rng1.Row (always zero!)
        Set Obj = UserForm1.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1")...  
        Set Obj = UserForm1.Controls.Add("forms.checkbox.1")...
Next
```

Thanks by advance for any help

Comment: If `rng1 = Ws.Cells`, then `rng1.Row` is always 1. Perhaps you need to work with the filtered cells (maybe use `Range.SpecialCells` and `xlCellTypeVisible`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is exactly my question, how to get a kind of output range obtained from the sheet and after filtering and sorting. A kind of (select where order by). Is it clearer ?

Comment: Yep. Maybe take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065610/vba-selecting-visible-cells-after-filtering). That should get you started.